# Would the orbit of the Moon affect Earth's climate?

Tags: the-moon, orbit, climate

If the orbit of the Moon was elliptical or in someway different from what it is currently, would that change affect the climate of the Earth?

Comment: Yes, but not sure this is in scope.  If the question was centered on a planet other than Earth it would be a better fit.

Comment: @JamesJenkins We dealt with this issue over at Astronomy, and the decision was to allow general space questions directed at Earth and questions about Earth that involve other astronomical bodies (e.g. the Moon), but that specific geoscience questions would be off topic. http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/140/how-do-we-determine-what-geoscience-questions-are-in-scope

Comment: @JamesJenkins Not that we have to do the same here, but it provides some prior discussion.

Comment: The orbit of the moon is already elliptical. Perigee is 362600 km, apogee is 405400 km.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important effect of the Moon on the Earth is tides. The act of transporting huge amounts of water around is important for circulation and exchange of matter, and is also making the shore line a wide and ecological interesting area. If the Moon had another orbit, the tides would have another strength or frequency.
Microbiological life in the top layer of the ocean is responsible for a lot of the [photosynthesis](http://science.opposingviews.com/photosynthesis-place-ocean-5104.html), important for the composition of the atmosphere. They are dependant on the transport of nutrients between coastal and open ocean zones.
The Moon may also [protect the Earth from meteorites](http://www.intelligentdesigntheory.info/moon_comet_meteor_shower_asteroid_planet_earth.htm), event though that is [disputed.](http://www.answers.com/Q/Does_the_moon_protect_the_earth_from_asteroids)